# Conformal group of a ball

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, conformal-geometry

What are the generators of the conformal group of the Euclidean $n$-dimensional ball? Where can I learn more about conformal groups?

Any reference will be very appreciated!

Comment: In two dimensions you should think about the uniqueness property of the [Riemann mapping theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_mapping_theorem). In higher dimensions you need [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_theorem_(conformal_mappings)). Either way, you should end up with the Moebius group  $SO^+(n+1,1)$.